# How to get Array from user

Tags: java

This program is working but I want take A[] array input from the user. Please somebody tell me how to take input from the user and use that input as an array in the program.

```
 public class rough1{
 public static int arrMajority1(int A[]){
 int n = A.length;

 for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
 int c = 1;
 for(int j=i+1;j<A.length;j++)
 if (A[i]==A[j])
  c=c+1;
  if (c>(A.length/2)){
  return A[i];
  }
  }

   return -1;
  }

   public static void main(String[] args){
    int A[] = new int [] {1,1,7,5};
   // int arrMajority1 = A[0];
     if (arrMajority1(A) != -1)

    System.out.println("The majority element is " + arrMajority1(A));

    else 
    System.out.println("There is no majority element.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to read input from the user. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: You have to read in the numbers from the user and place them into an array in your code. Take a look at Java's Scanner class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not give you the code because for your own good you need to do a bit of research. But here are pointers:

1. use Scanner to get user's input.
2. put the input into an ArrayList.
3. find the method of List that produce an array.